# GlobalSession using struts2

Tags: struts2

I want to maintain a list of objects in global session using struts so that if there are multiple users editing the list each user should see the updated list.

```
   @Action(value = "/listAuthoredFiles", results = { @Result(name = "success", type = "json", params = {
    "excludeProperties", "gridModel.*\\.*Map, gridModel.*\\.*List" }) })
public String execute() throws Exception {

    log.debug("Page: " + getPage() + " Rows: " + getRows() + " Sorting Order: " + getSord() + " Index Row: " + getSidx());

   List<FilterParameter> filters = getFilterParameters();
   List<UserVO> gridModel = new ArrayList<UserVO>();
   if (!CommonUtil.isEmpty(filters)) {
        gridModel = searchService.findByCriteria(filters);
     } else {
        log.debug("filters is empty");
    }
    ActionContext.getContext().getSession().put(SearchConstants.LIST_AUTHORED_FILES, gridModel);
```

In another action class i am accessing the list :

```
    if (MapUtils.isNotEmpty(ActionContext.getContext().getSession())
            && ActionContext.getContext().getSession().containsKey(SearchConstants.LIST_AUTHORED_FILES)) {
  List<UserVO> gridModel = (List<UserVO>) ActionContext.getContext().getSession()
                    .get(SearchConstants.LIST_AUTHORED_FILES);
```

but the problem here is if i put in session and if there are multiple users accessing this list then there would be possibility users won't be  seeing the updated list as i am storing the list in user's session not at global session level. So is there any way to store list in global session level.

Comment: Please share more details. code will be appreciated

Comment: Your "GlobalSession" is usually called "application scope". If you search Stackoverflow for this you should find plenty of answers to your problem. On a sidenote: Spring (which would be one way to solve your problem) actually provides a global-session scope which is absolutely NOT want you want.

Comment: @Stefan using spring we can do that but i want using struts application scope which you suggested. Can we set list in application scope like this `ServletActionContext.getContext().getApplication().put(KEY,VALUE)`    in one action class and in another action class we should check that list is there in application scope.

Comment: I just wanted to make you aware that in the case of Spring the term global session would be misleading.

Comment: Yes that should work.